# HttpContext.Current null when making a function Asynchronous in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am currently working on MVC4 in VS2010-SP1. I made one of the function in 
 the controller class Asynchronous. As part of that I made the controller class 
 derived from AsyncController and added the below two methods ( see code section 1 and 
 2 below). one method ending with Async(See Code Section 1 ) and another method ending 
 with Completed ( See Code Section 2 ). The problem is in the model class I am trying 
 to access my webservice with credentials from HttpContext ( See Code below 3 ). The 
 context is going null when making an asynchronous call. ie, In the new thread 
 httpcontext is not available. How to pass the context from main thread to new threads 
 created.

Code Section 1

```
public void SendPlotDataNewAsync(string fromDate, string toDate, string item)
{

         AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
                    var highChartModel = new HighChartViewModel();
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                          AsyncManager.Parameters["dataPlot"] = 
highChartModel.GetGraphPlotPointsNew(fromDate, toDate, item);
                          AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
                      });

}
```

Code Section 2

```
 public JsonResult SendPlotDataNewCompleted(Dictionary<string, List<ChartData>> 
 dataPlot)
 {
      return Json(new { Data = dataPlot });
 }
```

Code Section 3

```
public List<MeterReportData> GetMeterDataPointReading(MeterReadingRequestDto 
meterPlotData)
{

            var client = WcfClient.OpenWebServiceConnection<ReportReadingClient,   
IReportReading>(null, (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["WebserviceCredentials"] ?? 
string.Empty);

                try
                {
                    return 
ReadReportMapper.MeterReportReadMap(client.GetMeterDataPointReading(meterPlotData));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("MetaData Exception:{0},{1},{2},{3}", 
ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message, (ex.InnerException != null) ? 
ex.InnerException.Message : String.Empty, " ");
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    WcfClient.CloseWebServiceConnection<ReportReadingClient, 
IReportReading> (client);
                }

                }
```

Comment: Next time please try to do better job on the post and code formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is `null` because your task is executed on a pool thread without `AspNetSynchronizationContext` synchronization context.

Use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        AsyncManager.Parameters["dataPlot"] =
            highChartModel.GetGraphPlotPointsNew(fromDate, toDate, item);
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. When I add the above I got the error function StartNew cannot acccept the second parameter TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(). I am using MVC4 in VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. Working like a charm.